# Unbinding all canvas items in tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm really new to tkinter...

I'm unable to unbind canvas items in tkinter.

The items are binded by

```
self.canvas = Canvas(root, background="white")
self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="blue", tags=scale_index_tag)
self.canvas.tag_bind(scale_index_tag, "<ButtonPress-1>", self.Add_weight)
```

I have tried

```
self.canvas.unbind("<ButtonPress-1>")

self.canvas.unbind_all(self.Add_weight)

self.canvas.unbind_all("<ButtonPress-1>")
```

...no success.

I even tried to delete all the canvas items and regenerate them with no binding but still when I click the mouse, Add_weight-method is called...

```
self.canvas.delete(ALL)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use a `tag_bind` to bind the button, you're going to need to use `tag_unbind` to unbind it. Also, `unbind` (just like `bind`) takes 2 arguments, in this case the tag and the button.

```
self.canvas.tag_unbind(scale_index_tag, `"<ButtonPress-1>"`)
```

Comment: Okay. Does even canvas.destroy() destroy all the bindings?

Comment: how do I unbind all the tags (like what the original question was asking for).